# Difference between Android location geocoder and Google map API

Tags: android, geolocation, google-geocoder

In my Android application, I need to get the address of my co-ordinates got from GPS. Which is the best method to get it. By using android.location.Geocoder through following code ?

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(Booking.this);
try {
List<Address> add = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 3);
 Log.d("Geocode location", ""+add.get(0));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

or by using Google map API through this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=13.9020,80.3498&sensor=true ?

It will be helpful if some one guide the correct Geocoding  method.